# adding repeating sequence numbers to a column in SQLite database based on conditions

Tags: sqlite, sql-update

I added a column in my SQLite database, and I need to insert repeating sequence numbers, starting with 1...n BUT it's based on grouping by other columns. The sequence needs to start over at 1 again when there is a new grouping.

Here is my table:
`CREATE TABLE "ProdRunResults" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL  UNIQUE , "SeqNumbr" INTEGER, "Shift" INTEGER, "ShiftSeqNumbr" INTEGER, "Date" DATETIME, "ProdRunID" INTEGER, "Result" VARCHAR)`

[image]

ShiftSeqNumbr is the new column that I need to populate with sequence numbers, based on grouping of numbers in ProdRunID column then by numbers in the Shift column.

There could be up to 3 "shifts" (work shifts in a 24 hr period).

I scraped together some code to do this but it adds the sequence numbers to ShiftSeqNumbr column in reverse (descending) order:

```
UPDATE ProdRunResults 
SET ShiftSeqNumbr = (SELECT COUNT (*)
FROM ProdRunResults AS N
WHERE N.ProdRunID = ProdRunResults.ProdRunID
    AND N.Shift = ProdRunResults.Shift
    AND N.ShiftSeqNumbr = ProdRunResults.ShiftSeqNumbr);
```

[image]

How can I change the Update statement so the sequence numbers start at 1 and go up? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your UPDATE statement counts how many rows there are that have the same values in the `ProdRunID`/`Shift`/`ShiftSeqNumbr` columns as the current row. The current row always has an empty value in `ShiftSeqNumbr`, so it is counting how many rows in the current group have not yet been updated.

You need to count how many rows come before the current row, i.e., how many rows have the same `ProdRunID` and `Shift` values, and the same or a smaller `SeqNumbr` value:

```
UPDATE ProdRunResults 
SET ShiftSeqNumbr = (SELECT COUNT (*)
                     FROM ProdRunResults AS N
                     WHERE N.ProdRunID =  ProdRunResults.ProdRunID
                       AND N.Shift     =  ProdRunResults.Shift
                       AND N.SeqNumbr  <= ProdRunResults.SeqNumbr);
```

Comment: I knew there was flawed logic in there somewhere! Thank you. I actually had to make one small change to your suggestion because your example was giving me the same result (descending sequence numbers), but changing to a LT sign in the last condition fixed it: `UPDATE ProdRunResults 
SET ShiftSeqNumbr = (SELECT COUNT (*)
                     FROM ProdRunResults AS N
                     WHERE N.ProdRunID =  ProdRunResults.ProdRunID
                       AND N.Shift     =  ProdRunResults.Shift
                       AND N.SeqNumbr  <= ProdRunResults.SeqNumbr);`